# Unable to sync database in Django

Tags: django, python-2.7, oracle10g

I'm trying to create my first web application using Django.

I'm following the instructions given in the official Django documentation. (The first tutorial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/)

The server started successfully, but when I run the following command (from command prompt):

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

I'm getting the following error

```
ORA-12560: TNS: protocol adapter error
```

I'm able to access Oracle homepage by going to 127.0.0.1:8080/apex/

I have Oracle 10g database express edition installed on my system, along with the Oracle instant client.  After doing a Google search for the above error code, I've been presented with a variety of solutions — about adding ORACLE_HOME in environment variables and pointing that to

```
E:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\bin;
```

But that doesn't fix the issue.

I have also added

```
E:\instantclient;E:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server;
```

to the PATH variable.

I have Python 2.7 installed along with cx_Oracle. I have successfully checked the installation of cx_Oracle by importing it in python. Some of the solutions speak about an ORACLE_SID. I'm unable to find that.

As you can see, I'm a complete newbie to stackoverflow and programming. It's really discouraging to come across such a problem in my very first program. So please help me solve this issue.

Comment: if this is your first project **please** use the SQLite database rather than trying to configure oracle. Django is great fun and you're bogging yourself down in details before you've even started. Configuring production databases comes at the production stage.

Comment: Thanks @will. Do I have to download SQLite for using it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use SQLite3, you just need to modify your settings.py DATABASES field to something like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': '/path/to/mysite/database.db',  # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',                      # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo do not need to download SQLite explicitly. Django has inbuilt SQLite3 database engine.